# vue-router this.$route.params is empty

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to get a variable called `project_id` from the address bar using vue-router. I've initialized a router like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueRouter)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/project/:project_id', component: App }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

And tried to access `this.$route.params.project_id` from within my App.vue componenet:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <div id="center_bar">
      oh: {{this.$route.params.project_id}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProjectList from './components/ProjectList'
import ProjectAboutBox from './components/ProjectAboutBox'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  created() {
    console.dir(this.$route.params)
  },
  components: {
    ProjectList,
    ProjectAboutBox
  }
}
</script>
```

However, when I write `this.$route.params` to the console, I see that it is an empty object.

I didn't see anyone who encountered something similar, so my guess is that I'm missing something very basic, but I can't figure out exactly what it is.

In addition, if I `console.dir(this.$route)` I'm seeing that `fullPath` is "/", even though I'm accessing http://localhost:8080/project/kljkjkj/

**EDIT:**

I have also found that when I create a `<router-link>` that leads to the address I want to parse, then clicking on it make the whole thing work, just accessing it directly by typing the address in the address bar fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default vue-router is [hash mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html). You can try visit `http://localhost:8080/#/project/kljkjkj/`

You can change to history mode

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{ path: "/project/:project_id", component: App }]
});
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/p9v3172x6j (try to change url to https://p9v3172x6j.codesandbox.io/project/1234)

Comment: I actually just figured that out a minute ago and was about to answer my own question! Well, sort of, I figured out that I needed to add the hash symbol, but couldn't figure out why `vue-router` has this behavior! thank you!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!

Comment: Making it to history mode This doesn't make any sense . If i have used hash mode then I don't want to make it history just for this one thing there should be a logical reason.

Answer (score 8):

I come across a similar problem.

When manually enter url or refresh the browser, the $route object is not populated.

After some investigation, I found that if a lazy-loading route is matched:

**For components outside 'router-view':**
the $route object is not being populated even in the 'mounted' hook, but is populated later in the rendering process.

**For components inside 'router-view':**
the $route object is populated and available immediately

My fix is to use 'computed' property instead of 'data' when try to access variable inside the $route object.

**Version:**
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-router": "^3.2.0"

Node: Changing the mode from 'hash' to 'history' doesn't help in my case.

Comment: Ok, this was driving my insane. On a hot reload it would work as expected but a refresh or initial navigation it wouldn't. I ran into the issue and "fixed" it by just accessing the URL directly: `(new URL(location)).searchParams.get('locationId')`. I also was using "history" using Vue 2.6.10. This happened in my App.vue (top level file) and I tested created() and mounted().

Comment: this save me lots of time thx ;)

Comment: Instead of the computed property, you can also wait for the router to be ready before loading the app : `router.isReady().then(() => app.mount('#app'));` (credits: https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/vue-router-4-route-params-not-available-on-created-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

when in `<template>`you don't need to refer `this`.

have you tried:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <div id="center_bar">
      oh: {{$route.params.project_id}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

?

Also, I see that you are not using a `<router-view>`:

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view

Comment: When I'm not referring with `this`, it's not working at all. I have also found that when I create a `<router-link>` that leads to the address I want to parse, then clicking on it make the whole thing work, just accessing it directly by typing the address in the address bar fails

Comment: Currently, I have no need for `<router-view>`, I'm only loading one component, and I just want it to behave slightly differently based on the information in the address bar